# Cordova VS Capacitor for geolocation

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, qr-code, capacitor

need to know what is better for and geolocation and qr code , cordova or capacitor in IONIC, can explain the diferences and why is better ?

Comment: If you're starting a new Ionic project it defaults to Capacitor.

Comment: Capacitor is default in ionic?? you dont need to install it?

Comment: Assuming you're starting an app from the cli. `ionic start` Yes. https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/starting

Comment: so when i create my project need use `ionic start myApp tabs --capacitor` this for add capacitor in project , am i wrong?

Comment: Yes. Or just follow the prompts. The CLI will guide you.

Comment: thank you Mr.@johnborges , keep you safe